# What signals should I use to terminate/kill applications on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, signals, d

For POSIX environments it's easy. `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGKILL`, `SIGHUP`, etc.

But I am writing an application in D that needs to manage open applications based on user input, sending signals that the user requests. I need to know the equivalents of these signals for Windows, and their values. What are the most important ones? I found documentation for this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/signal), but it's not as comprehensive as POSIX documentation.

I will be using `std.process.kill(Pid pid, int codeOrSignal)` from the [D standard library documentation](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_process.html#kill), but I don't know what signals I need to send.

Thanks!

Edit: As discussed in the comments, I have tagged both C++ and D because answers in either language are helpful. The two languages are cross-compatible and very easy to port between eachother.

Comment: in windows not exist signals at all. for console applications you can use `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`.

Comment: The Windows POSIX compatibility layer is incomplete, so I suggest you find some other ways to kill a process. More Windows-specific ways.

Comment: @RbMm Unfortunately just for console applications that won't cut it. I need to be able to kill or terminate any application the user asks me to.

Comment: For Windows - "*If codeOrSignal is specified, it must be a nonnegative number which will be used as the exit code of the process. If not, the process will exit with code 1*" - so if you don't want to specify an exit code use the overload that does not offer `codeOrSignal` & don't worry about it.

Comment: can use `TerminateProcess`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Please revert your edit. This question matters as much for C++ as it does for D. The languages are cross-compatible and use the same methods.

Comment: If you program in one specific language and want a solution in that language, then you should not tag other languages. And if you want solutions in multiple languages, then the question becomes to broad.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Asking help from C++ programmers is just as useful to me as D programmers. I tag C++ in my D questions because the answers are going to be basically the same, and I have a better chance of getting a C++ answer because of the increased popularity.

Comment: You can rollback the edit yourself, or re-edit it. But be warned that there will be votes to close it as to broad. You have read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) And [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? And [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)?

Comment: `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` is equivalent to `killpg` for console applications, *not* `kill`. You have to be attached to the console (e.g. via `AttachConsole`). Either target a known process group (only possible if you created the group via  `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`, since WinAPI has no function to query the group ID) or use group 0 to send the event to all attached processes, including your own. A new group has Ctrl+C disabled until it enables it via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`, so you can only reliably send Ctrl+Break to a non-zero group ID.

Comment: For GUI apps in the current session, you can combine `EnumWindows` and `FindWindowEx` to enumerate all top-level and message-only windows. Filter to a process ID via `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and send each window `WM_CLOSE`. Note that the a console window elects one process as its effective owner, which is initially the process that allocated the console. Sending `WM_CLOSE` to the console window will kill every process that's attached to the console. Each gets a Ctrl+Close event, which gives it 5 seconds to exit before getting terminated forcefully by csrss.exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does not have signals.
If you literally want to terminate applications then call `TerminateProcess`. This can cause it to corrupt any files it is writing to.

If causing corruption is not your goal, then you can close console applications via `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` and GUI applications can be closed by posting their window (or windows) WM_CLOSE messages.

Some apps respond to WM_CLOSE by showing modal dialogs that prompt the user to save files, so you might need to have a timeout on the process handle and just call TerminateProcess anyway if it takes too long.

---

As noted, unless your application was involved in actually launching console applications you have no way to actually meet the requirements to call `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`, which is unfortunate. Even if attached to a console window that can handle WM_CLOSE events, unless this is a secret way to send ctrl events, the console apps themselves will be unable to respond to WM_CLOSE messages to clean up properly, so you just have to hope for the best and use `TerminateProcess`.

Documentation:
[`TerminateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms918433.aspx),
[`GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent),
[`WM_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-close)

Comment: `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` is the equivalent of Unix `killpg`. It requires being attached to the same console. Calling it on a PID of a process group leader (i.e. created via `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`) sends the event to all processes in the group that are attached to the console. The behavior is undefined if it's not a group ID. What I observe is that the console handles it like group 0, which broadcasts the event to all attached processes, including the calling process. I've seen this function misused a lot since Windows process groups are poorly documented and can't be queried.

Comment: I wish Windows would add a `GenerateConsoleCtrlEventEx` function that allows sending control events (including `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`) to an individual process as well as process groups. Then we could use `AttachConsole(processId)` and `GenerateConsolCtrlEventEx(CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, processId, TARGET_IS_PROCESS_ID)`. Sending a Ctrl+Close event would behave the same, i.e. the application has 5 seconds to exit before csrss.exe calls `TerminateProcess`, but it's only one process/group getting terminated, as opposed to sending `WM_CLOSE` to the console window, which terminates all attached processes.